# PHP variable Interpolation, why it works

Tags: php, arrays

Given this setup

```
$names = array('Smith', 'Jones', 'Jackson');
```

I understand that this works:

```
echo "Citation: {$names[1]}[1987]".PHP_EOL; //Citation: Jones[1987]
```

PHP through the complex syntax with curly braces, is pulling the value of the second element on the array and the [1987] is just another text...

But in the next code:

```
echo "Citation: $names[1][1987]".PHP_EOL;
```

I'd expect an error, I'd expect PHP interprets it as a two dimensional array and thrown an error, but instead it gave me same output that the code above "Citation: Jones[1987]"

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP goes here for the first occurrence of `]`, since you have an array, as you can see in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Similarly, an **array index or an object property can be parsed**. With array indices, the **closing square bracket (]) marks the end of the index**. The same rules apply to object properties as to simple variables.

This means the end is the first index, e.g.

```
echo "Citation: $names[1][1987]".PHP_EOL;
              //^ Start ^ End
```

So that means your "second dimension" is just parsed as a normal string. So for more complex structures you have to use the complex syntax to mark the start and the end of your variable, e.g.

```
echo "Citation: {$names[1][1987]}".PHP_EOL;
              //^ See here      ^
```

So this will give you the warning:

> Notice:  Uninitialized string offset: 1987

Comment: Thanks... IMHO it should say "... With array indices, the FIRST closing square bracket (]) marks the end of the index ..."